# What is a purpose of ZoneId in java.time.Clock?

Tags: java, clock

We can create Instant from Clock. Clock has a timezone.

```
Clock clock1 = Clock.system(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
Clock clock2 = Clock.system(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
System.out.println("Clock1 instant: " + clock1.instant());
System.out.println("Clock2 instant: " + clock2.instant());
```

The output gives the same instant:

> Clock1 instant: 2022-01-21T18:36:21.848Z
> Clock2 instant: 2022-01-21T18:36:21.848Z

So what is a purpose of having a timezone in Clock?

Comment: Honestly, it's a misdesigned API.  You're right that it doesn't really belong there.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Read the JavaDoc for `java.time.clock`.  It is there as a shim to allow injection of custom or mocked clocks for testing.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Your comment doesn't make sense to me. `Instant` isn't the only thing you can create from a `Clock`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `Instant`

You said:

> The output gives the same instant:

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment **as seen in UTC**, that is, with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. So your code makes no use of your specified time zones.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Instead, try [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). This class does make use of the time zone. For example, calling `ZonedDateTime.now()` captures the current moment as seen in the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s current default time zone. Calling `ZonedDateTime.now( myClock )` captures the current moment tracked by that [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) object as seen through that `Clock` object’s assigned time zone.

```
System.out.println("Clock1 ZonedDateTime.now: " + ZonedDateTime.now( clock1 ) );
System.out.println("Clock2 ZonedDateTime.now: " + ZonedDateTime.now( clock2 ) );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6UHmUy). By the way, there we use the new time zone name [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) rather than `Asia/Calcutta`.

Notice the different time of day, 16:21 versus 20:51. And notice the different time zone.

```
Clock1 ZonedDateTime.now: 2022-01-22T16:21:26.490913+01:00[Europe/Paris]
Clock2 ZonedDateTime.now: 2022-01-22T20:51:26.492823+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

## Used in testing

You asked:

> So what is a purpose of having a timezone in Clock?

This functionality is useful for [testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing), where we need to create a known scenario with a specific time zone rather than using the JVM’s actual default time zone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a really helpful answer.